# failed to open stream in php

Tags: php, path, include

I get this error on a simple `include` method:

```
Warning:  include(/home/content/70/8352870/html/sites/mysite.com/preview/wp-content/themes/site-theme/mail/class.phpmailer.php)
[<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/70/8352870/html/sites/mysite.com/preview/wp-content/themes/site-theme/mail/send-message.php on line 5
```

I've included the file using this:

```
<?php
    $path = getcwd();
    include $path.'/class.phpmailer.php';
?>
```

I get the same error without using `getcwd` method but this:

```
include 'class.phpmailer.php';

Warning:  include(class.phpmailer.php)
[<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/70/8352870/html/sites/mysite.com/preview/wp-content/themes/site-theme/mail/send-message.php on line 10
```

Obiouvsly I checked the files are located here:

```
mysite.com/preview/wp-content/themes/site-theme/mail/
class.phpmailer.php
class.pop3.php
class.smtp.php
send-message.php
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: And `class.phpmailer.php` is definitely in `/home/content/70/8352870/html/sites/mysite.com/preview/wp-content/themes/site-theme/mail`?

Comment: Can you show `print_r(glob(getcwd().'/*.php'));`

Comment: Right, I'll check again, i'm using coda and sometimes make tricks

Answer (score 0):

This has the same behavior that you are trying to get, but is more trusted:

(I suppose that class.phpmailer is on the same path the the script that is including it)

```
<?php
$path = dirname( __FILE__ );
include $path.'/class.phpmailer.php';
?>
```

Comment: FYI, since 5.3 `__DIR__ === dirname( __FILE__ )`. And neither are identical to `getcwd()` because the current working directory is not necessarily the location of the current script.